# Conditional formatting excel to access (SQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm not that familiar with access/SQL and am trying to convert a conditional formatting expression that works in Excel over to access.

Here is the Excel function:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("<",G249)),VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(G249,"<",""))>14)
```

If both of these are true, then the cell is formatted a certain way. Is there a way to convert this to SQL?

Thank you.

Comment: You should tag access if that's where you are seeking in a solution. You should also explain the formula. Sample data and desired output is ideal.

Comment: how does cell g249 look like `<12`

Comment: Not without knowing your data structure and data. None of those functions have any meaning in Access. Possible Access equivalents: SEARCH() maybe InStr(); SUBSTITUTE() would be Replace(); VALUE() maybe Val(); ISNUMBER() would be IsNumeric(). Then you have to reference controls instead of cells. Provide sample data of textbox to reference.

Comment: Basic syntax would be: `IIf(this condition AND another condition, this, else this)`. However, an expression in SQL has nothing to do with Conditional Formatting.

Comment: Basically I am dealing with laboratory data that I would like to flag if it’s over a certain value. Sometimes the lab adds qualifiers to the value which mean different things but I would like retained. An example would be a value of <100 but I would like to compare it to a regulatory limit of 5. Or sometimes will have 2 qualifiers like <100J. I just want to remove those qualifiers and compare the numerical value to a value that I designate and then highlight if it exceeds. The problem is these qualified values are present amongst hundreds of regular numerical values.

Comment: So I just need an expression in Access for conditional formatting of a report that can do this. The excel version works but something in access would be far better since I’m dealing with the database directly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: in Access, VBA doesn't work well with conditional formatting. 
 Here are some official instructions: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/highlight-data-with-conditional-formatting-7f7c0bd4-7c37-421d-adad-a260125c8129  My suggestion is to change the structure of your data.  use vba to clean each cell of its qualifiers, but store each qualifier in a table of qualifiers with the qualifiers associated recordIDs.  Then in your reports and queries you can get some type of validation working by adding a calculated field that uses dlookup to check for any qualifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not do the conditional formatting in the sql statement.  It is performed by going into the Format menu and selecting the Conditional Formatting item.
Based on the function you've provided, I would do something similar to the example shown here:
[image]

Ensure you replace the [G249] portion with your field name.

The only other thing that should be mentioned, is the text that may follow the number, such as that 'J'.  in which case I would encase the number with the Val function, example:

```
Val(Replace([G249],"<",""))
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I inserted the Val function for a full expression as follows:

`IIf(InStr([Methyl tert-Butyl Ether],""),IIf(IsNumeric(Val(Replace([Methyl tert-Butyl Ether],"<",""))),Val(Replace([Methyl tert-Butyl Ether],"<","")),0),0)>14`

The only issue that I had was that if a value had only a J at the end, it didn't format, so I added:
`Replace([Methyl tert-Butyl Ether],"J","")>14`